# ASA5506 VPN Client Blocked

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, cisco-asa

I am setting a new CISCO ASA5506.

I am testing a CISCO VPN Client, IPSec/UDP, and it is being blocked. I'm not even prompted for a credentials.

The VPN Connection works just fine from another network in our office and I've used the VPN Connection to connect from hotels and other random places. I know it's not the remote VPN setup that is the issue.

On the ASA5506 no traffic being blocked. 
I've added a default inspection for IPSec-Pass-Thru.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not following this very well.  Are you trying to use AnyConnect, or some other piece of VPN software?  Where are you testing from in relation to the ASA?  Would it be possible for you to post log output from AnyConnect and a sanitized show run from the Asa?

Comment: I'm using Cisco's VPN Client. This is the path. From my desktop I use CISCO VPN CLIENT >> New ASA 5506 >> Internet >> Remote ASA 5510.  When I am behind the ASA5506, the VPN client shows no log. It's like not even connecting through the first phase of an IPSec connection. Thanks Rob.

Comment: Cisco has two VPN clients that you're likely between, AnyConnect and the old (discontinued) thing that was specifically called "Cisco VPN Client".  Just to warn you, the latter has been discontinued for quite some time - longer than the 5506 has been available for sale for.  I believe you could get a 5506 to work with it, but the defaults are very likely different than what the old software will work with.  So it's critical to know if it is Cisco's AnyConnect VPN Client, or the old 'Cisco VPN Client' thing.  What's the version number of the software you're trying to use?

Comment: Looks like it was a false alarm. After adding the IPSec-Pass-Thru inspection, it probably  worked after that. Windows 10 had a pending update. thanks for the assistance.